# Dynamic Codeigniter's Form Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

**Target**
Mobile field is optional, and depending whether it has or has no value, there will be a validation rule to it, accordingly. But seems like, that even though the right validation rule is set, it always return true for the mobile field.

**My Code**

```
$client['mobile'] = "asdf";

$config = array(
 'member_form' => array(
   array( 'field' => 'client[firstName]', 'label' => 'First Name', 'rules' => 'required|trim'),
   array( 'field' => 'client[lastName]', 'label' => 'Last Name', 'rules' => 'required|trim')
);

if($client["mobile"])
 array_push($config["member_form"], array( 'field' => 'client[mobile]', 'label' => 'Mobile Number', 'rules' => 'required|trim|numeric'));
else
 array_push($config["member_form"], array( 'field' => 'client[mobile]', 'label' => 'Mobile Number', 'rules' => 'trim'));

if ($this->form_validation->run("member_form") == TRUE) {
 . . .
} else {
 . . .
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try: if($client['mobile'] != '') { ... } else { ... }

Comment: @Sata is $config from form_validation.php?

Comment: @loki9 - Yes, "Saving Sets of Validation Rules to a Config File" from https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html